# "Отвисание" окна после определенного времени

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть компонент, получающий данные. сколько будет по времени это получение - неизвестно. нужен механизм, оповещающий пользователя, что "я еще живой". есть два этапа поведения получения данных:

1. До определенного момента времени компонент ведет себя естественным образом, попросту говоря "висит"
2. Если (когда?) достигнут "порог ожидания" - компонент как бы "отмирает" и появляется окно со счетчиком времени (конечно, учитывая провисённое время)

Каким образом лучше всего это реализовать?

Comment: Под компонентом вы имеете в виду графический компонент? И он получает данные в UI-потоке?

Comment: @VladD да, обычный UI-control

Comment: Окей, хорошо. Тогда есть сразу две проблемы: (1) Почему длинное чтение данных происходит в UI-потоке? (2) Почему этим занимается UI-контрол, а не класс модели?

Comment: @VladD исторически сложилось) класс модели здесь представлен максимум как DataTable, которая и заполняется адаптером, после чего конечный результат и передается UI-элементу

Comment: Ну допустим, а почему в UI-потоке?

Comment: @VladD опять же, исторически. Можно вывести это в отдельный поток, сути это не меняет. Сначала нужно лочить контрол и "отлипать", когда ожидание затянулось

Comment: Не, тут не «можно», тут «нужно», Во-первых, зависший UI выглядит _очень_ некрасиво с точки зрения пользователя, так что выгружать тяжёлые операции обязательно. Во-вторых, во время зависания UI обновить в принципе нельзя. Так что придётся выгрузить в фоновый поток.